# Automatically go into list view when going to a folder

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

When clicking on a folder in TYPO3 CMS backend, I get this message:

> The current page is a folder. Folders usually don't contain content elements but are used for collecting other types of records.

Can I make TYPO3 go into list view automatically? I don't see no reason why it stays in page view when going to a folder.

Reversely, I'd like to go into page view when clicking on a page.

Ugh, found an issue from 2011....... https://forge.typo3.org/issues/29790 Fix, please!!

Comment: Although auto-switch to List view would be nice option, in other direction it's not so obvious, remember, that your normal page (not sysfolder) can store some records i.e. from extensions, which can be accessed via List, and for granulation reason they are placed exactly on this PID.

Comment: Still, it would be nice if the editor had the choice, e.g. a Typoscript option to configure this behaviour.

Comment: I can see your point of view, anyway there are millions of things "nice to have", all we can to do with it is to create a working sample with pull request.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'll have time next week...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an extension 'autoswitchlistview' which does exactly what you're looking for:

> Whenever you are in the page module and clicking on a sys folder in the page tree, you will be forwarded to list view automatically.

[View Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/georgringer/autoswitchtolistview)

Comment: Cool! Will it autoswitch to page view when visiting a page?

Comment: Hm, no it didn't. FFFFFUUUUUU

Comment: It should be straight forward to extend it that way. Take a look at [Line 42 in the PageLayoutController](https://github.com/georgringer/autoswitchtolistview/blob/master/Hooks/PageLayoutController.php#L42), and duplicate the part to cover the page view as well..

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look!